# How do I get outputs at fixed steps?

Tags: r, desolve

I have a system of differential equations, there a bit complex but the closest analogy I can come to is for a catalized checmical reaction where the catalist decomposes over time, e.g.

```
A + B -> C + B  (rate k1)
B -> D          (rate k2)
```

So we have `dAdt(A,B) = -k1*A*B` and `dBbt(a,B) = -k2*B`

I can model this with `rk4` and a fixed set of time points... but I want to run this until say B < 1e-8

I think this can be done by using root functions in the general `ode` package but that also only takes a `times` parameter which forces me to pick in advance the times I want the "concentrations of A and B" for.

Note: my real equations are more complex and actually quite involved to compute - they have nothing to do with chemistry other than the values are all positive numbers and once one is as close to zero as makes no odds, the state of the system stops changing.

I have a hand-rolled RK4 implementation that does what I want, but code I write is code I need to test, I know the `deSolve` package is well tested so I'm just looking for a way to get the outputs at fixed step sizes *until* a "root" function returns true

## Update

Here's an example of solving my problem where I know the times I want the answer at:

```
kernel <- function(t, y, params, input) {
  with(as.list(c(params,y)), {
    dA <- -k1*A*B
    dB <- -k2*B
    list(c(dA,dB))
  })
}
params <- c(k1=0.03, k2=0.005)
y0 <- c(A=1.3, B=0.5)

# here I need to pick the times!
times <- seq(0,500, by=1)
out <- rk4(y0, times, kernel, params)
```

What I want is something like "Change the last two lines of your code to this"

```
out <- ___name_of_function___(
  y0, 
  initial_time=0, 
  delta_time=1, 
  kernel, 
  params, 
  rootfun=function(t,y,p){y.B<1e-8}
)
```

Where `__name_of_function__` is hopefully some function in the `deSolve` package or a related helper package

Answer (score 0):

Example 2 in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.28/topics/lsodar shows that the general approach hints that for two calls to the solver,  we can have the second call evaluate all the required points, at the expense of no control over the number of evaluations in the first call:

```
kernel <- function(t, y, params, input) {
  with(as.list(c(params,y)), {
    dA <- -k1*A*B
    dB <- -k2*B
    list(c(dA,dB))
  })
}
params <- c(k1=0.03, k2=0.005)
y0 <- c(A=1.3, B=0.5)
rootfun <- function(t, y, params, input) {
  with(as.list(c(params,y)), {
    ifelse(B<1e-8,0,B)
  })
}

# First find where the root is
out <- ode(y0, c(0,1e8), kernel, params, root=rootfun)
# Now the second rwo of `out` will be the location of the root
# So just create the times up to that point
times <- seq(0,round(out[2,'time']), by=1)
out <- ode(y0, times, kernel, params, root = rootfun)
```

NOTE: The number of evaluations of the function during to root finding is limited by maxsteps which will default to 500

Comment: I don't like this as I need to invoke `ode` twice

Comment: If you have a better answer that evaluates only as many calls as required to reach the root and doesn’t require `seq(0,1e8,by=1)` style vector allocation, I’ll give your answer the checkmark

Comment: Good question, I had to read it twice to get to the point -- hopefully ;-) What about employing an event with a terminal root, see `?events`. Not sure if this is the right path, but let's think about it.

Comment: Always nice to get a comment from the package author!!!

Comment: If it were me, I’d allow `times` parameter to be a function taking one parameter (the current time) and returning the next time. Eg `function(time=0){time+1}` that way it’s like a generator function. The default value for the parameter is the initial time ;-) Given permitted values of `times` are currently a vector a single value or `NULL` (in some cases) it’s backwards compatible as a means for extension

Comment: Tricky to confirm on my phone but all the other ODE solvers I looked at use fixed limits... didn’t check the Julia based one as that would complicate my CI pipeline for processing (and here’s a hint why I don’t want to specify an upper limit... I’m trying to automate something so trying to put heuristics in place to validate assumptions... no human will be directly looking at the solution

Comment: `times` is a vector for efficiency reasons: arrays are allocated for the return values in R and then the C or Fortran routines can do stateless number crunching. This is in particular important for the odepack solvers using highly optimized legacy routines. However, if you can live with a solver, written in plain R, one may consider a specialized rk solver for this, e.g. ode45. Another option (that we indeed sometimes use) is a what we call "stop and go mode" consisting of a chain of solver calls.